# How do I round to the nearest 0.5?

Tags: c#, math, function

I have to display ratings and for that, I need increments as follows:

| Input | Rounded |
| --- | --- |
| 1.0 | 1 |
| 1.1 | 1 |
| 1.2 | 1 |
| 1.3 | 1.5 |
| 1.4 | 1.5 |
| 1.5 | 1.5 |
| 1.6 | 1.5 |
| 1.7 | 1.5 |
| 1.8 | 2.0 |
| 1.9 | 2.0 |
| 2.0 | 2.0 |
| 2.1 | 2.0 |

and so on...

Is there a simple way to compute the required values?

Comment: "and so on..." does that include finite numbers close to the maximum representable value?

Answer (score 249, accepted):

Multiply your rating by 2, then round using `Math.Round(rating, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)`, then divide that value by 2.

`Math.Round(value * 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero) / 2`

Comment: Not perfect! what about integer overflow! You can compute only half of the possible integers.

Comment: @Elazar - if you could be ranked as high as 1,073,741,823rd, I can't think of a single use case where you would care if it's "one billion one and a half" or "one billion one" - if that's really a problem then there is something inherently flawed with the ranking scheme :)

Comment: @Elazar If you suspect that might be a problem you can use: x1 = Math.floor(rating); x1 = x1 + Math.round((rating - x1) * 2) / 2.0

Comment: @John, the rating could be used for something other than display, for instance, it might be consumed for another computation, and decide to display all the 10 items ranked  instead of those 10 items ranked `1,072,741,83.5`

Comment: Divide first, then multiply. This will eliminate the overflow problem, and also allow you to round to an arbitrary number.

Comment: @Benjol, dividing first and then rounding will cause it to round to the nearest factor of 2, rather than factor of one half. Not correct.

Comment: Corner: Certainly `value * 2` itself is subject to overflow with large `value` resulting in an incorrect result.

Comment: I'm having 8.95 decimal and when rounding it using your way, it becomes 9.00 and I'm a bit weird how to get it stay if it already .5

Comment: @ElazarLeibovich concerns of overflow can be side-step by using the number's fraction instead. `var fraction = rating - Math.floor(rating)`, then round this fraction instead or the original number.

Answer (score 81):

Multiply by 2, round, then divide by 2

if you want nearest quarter, multiply by 4, divide by 4, etc

Answer (score 25):

Here are a couple of methods I wrote that will always round up or down to any value.

```
public static Double RoundUpToNearest(Double passednumber, Double roundto)
{
    // 105.5 up to nearest 1 = 106
    // 105.5 up to nearest 10 = 110
    // 105.5 up to nearest 7 = 112
    // 105.5 up to nearest 100 = 200
    // 105.5 up to nearest 0.2 = 105.6
    // 105.5 up to nearest 0.3 = 105.6

    //if no rounto then just pass original number back
    if (roundto == 0)
    {
        return passednumber;
    }
    else
    {
        return Math.Ceiling(passednumber / roundto) * roundto;
    }
}

public static Double RoundDownToNearest(Double passednumber, Double roundto)
{
    // 105.5 down to nearest 1 = 105
    // 105.5 down to nearest 10 = 100
    // 105.5 down to nearest 7 = 105
    // 105.5 down to nearest 100 = 100
    // 105.5 down to nearest 0.2 = 105.4
    // 105.5 down to nearest 0.3 = 105.3

    //if no rounto then just pass original number back
    if (roundto == 0)
    {
        return passednumber;
    }
    else
    {
        return Math.Floor(passednumber / roundto) * roundto;
    }
}
```

Comment: Very Nice. We may add a third overload with `Math.Round`:
`return ((NearestΑttractor != 0) ? Math.Round(passednumber / NearestΑttractor) * NearestΑttractor : passednumber); `

Answer (score 2):

There are several options.  If performance is a concern, test them to see which works fastest in a large loop.

```
double Adjust(double input)
{
    double whole = Math.Truncate(input);
    double remainder = input - whole;
    if (remainder < 0.3)
    {
        remainder = 0;
    }
    else if (remainder < 0.8)
    {
        remainder = 0.5;
    }
    else
    {
        remainder = 1;
    }
    return whole + remainder;
}
```

Comment: This should work, but it just isn't as elegant as some solutions given. Multiplying and using the system library is just sexy.

Comment: Performance is usually more important, and this could end up taking less time than the multiplication and division solutions.

Comment: This code is not correct. Since arithmetic with doubles usually has some small rounding errors, an operation such as 4.8 - 4.0 could give for example 0.799999... . In this case  the code above would round to 4.5. Also better would to use Math.Floor instead of Math.Truncate, because right now negative numbers are not corretly rounded. I prefer the accepted answer,because it is simpler and less prone to implementation errors.

Answer (score 2):

These lines of code snap a float dx to nearest snap:

```
if (snap <= 1f)
    dx = Mathf.Floor(dx) + (Mathf.Round((dx - Mathf.Floor(dx)) * (1f / snap)) * snap);
else
    dx = Mathf.Round(dx / snap) * snap;
```

So if snap is 0.5, value gets rounded to nearest 0.5 value (1.37 goes to 1.5), if it is 0.02, value is rounded to nearest 0.02 ((1.37 goes to 1.38)). If snap is 3, value is rounded to nearest 3 (7.4 goes to 6, 7.6 goes to 9) etc... I use it to quickly snap objects on scene in unity because unity default snapping doesn't seem to work well for me.

Comment: This is the only code on this page which worked 100% of the time for me!
Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
decimal d = // your number..

decimal t = d - Math.Floor(d);
if(t >= 0.3d && t <= 0.7d)
{
    return Math.Floor(d) + 0.5d;
}
else if(t>0.7d)
    return Math.Ceil(d);
return Math.Floor(d);
```

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need to round to the nearest 0.5.  I see no version of `round` in the C# API that does this (one version takes a number of decimal digits to round to, which isn't the same thing).

Assuming you only have to deal with integer numbers of tenths, it's sufficient to calculate `round (num * 2) / 2`.  If you're using arbitrarily precise decimals, it gets trickier.  Let's hope you don't.

Answer (score 0):

```
Public Function Round(ByVal text As TextBox) As Integer
    Dim r As String = Nothing
    If text.TextLength > 3 Then
        Dim Last3 As String = (text.Text.Substring(text.Text.Length - 3))
        If Last3.Substring(0, 1) = "." Then
            Dim dimcalvalue As String = Last3.Substring(Last3.Length - 2)
            If Val(dimcalvalue) >= 50 Then
                text.Text = Val(text.Text) - Val(Last3)
                text.Text = Val(text.Text) + 1
            ElseIf Val(dimcalvalue) < 50 Then
                text.Text = Val(text.Text) - Val(Last3)
            End If
        End If
    End If
    Return r
End Function
```

Comment: This code does not look like C# as wanted in the question. What does it do? Please provide some explanation rather than just a lump of code in an unspecified language.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is taken from Rosdi Kasim's comment in the answer that John Rasch provided.

John's answer works but does have an overflow possibility.

Here is my version of Rosdi's code:

I also put it in an extension to make it easy to use.  The extension is not necessary and could be used as a function without issue.

```
<Extension>
Public Function ToHalf(value As Decimal) As Decimal
    Dim integerPart = Decimal.Truncate(value)
    Dim fractionPart = value - Decimal.Truncate(integerPart)
    Dim roundedFractionPart = Math.Round(fractionPart * 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero) / 2
    Dim newValue = integerPart + roundedFractionPart
    Return newValue
End Function
```

The usage would then be:

```
Dim newValue = CDec(1.26).ToHalf
```

This would return 1.5

Answer (score -1):

I had difficulty with this problem as well. 
I code mainly in Actionscript 3.0 which is base coding for the Adobe Flash Platform, but there are simularities in the Languages:

The solution I came up with is the following:

```
//Code for Rounding to the nearest 0.05
var r:Number = Math.random() * 10;  // NUMBER - Input Your Number here
var n:int = r * 10;   // INTEGER - Shift Decimal 2 places to right
var f:int = Math.round(r * 10 - n) * 5;// INTEGER - Test 1 or 0 then convert to 5
var d:Number = (n + (f / 10)) / 10; //  NUMBER - Re-assemble the number

trace("ORG No: " + r);
trace("NEW No: " + d);
```

Thats pretty much it. 
Note the use of 'Numbers' and 'Integers' and the way they are processed.

Good Luck!