# C# : How to round up float value to nearest float value?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a datagridview column 'total',in which I am doing sum of rates of respective items entered.Sometimes I am getting addition like 30.19 Rupees or 100.59 rupees,I want to make 30.19 to 30.50 & 100.59 to 101.So can anyone plz help me..?

i have tried

```
                float val = float.Parse(value);
                total = val;

                ekunrakam = ekunrakam + total;
                Math.Round(ekunrakam + 0.5,2);
```

but its not working..

thanks in advance..

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I round to the nearest 0.5?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1329426/how-do-i-round-to-the-nearest-0-5)

Comment: What did you try so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want Math.Round(Somefloat + 0.5,2) will do the job.

Answer (score 2):

Usually with currency, in the cases where you don't have a dedicated currency type, you use the smallest unit of currency that exists, paise or cents or what have you.

Also, don't use floats for money, or the rounding errors will get you.
These folk suggest Decimal.

[What is the best data type to use for money in c#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/693372/what-is-the-best-data-type-to-use-for-money-in-c)

Most countries have an official standard for how to round fractional amounts of currency, sometimes required by law, but they usually are some variant of bankers rounding. Which as luck will have it is the default behaviour of Decimal.Round.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.decimal.round%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If you were wanting to round to the nearest whole number, like 100.59 to 101, I would tell you to just set your float variable to an int.  But, why do you want to round up to 30.50?  What are your specific rules for rounding?

Comment: if m getting 30.19, In india 0.19 paise dont have any meaning.So I wan to round up to 0.50 paise.I am telling both the possiblities which am having..