# Rounding off to nearest 0.5 in matlab

Tags: matlab, math

How can I round off a decimal to the nearest 0.5 in matlab? E.g. I want 16.625 to be rounded to 16.5

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It's the same logic, the same question was made for [C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1329426/how-do-i-round-to-the-nearest-0-5)

```
result = round(value*2)/2;
```

And to generalize, according to [aardvarkk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/618068/aardvarkk)'s suggestion, if you want to round to the closest accuracy `acc`, for example `acc = 0.5`:

```
acc = 0.5;
result = round(value/acc)*acc;
```

Comment: This gives the correct answer -- mine doesn't! I'll delete mine, but I'd recommend you generalize the result (i.e. what if we wanted to round to the nearest 0.05...)

Comment: yes, I was actually typing a comment to your answer, I will edit mine.

Comment: To remove numerical noise from the output, you may round it once again by specifying number of decimal digits (Matlab 2018 supports this functionality). result = round(acc*round(value/acc),1); This will ensure a single digit. .499999 and .5000001 etc. will round to .5

Answer (score 3):

If you go the multiply by 2 - round - divide by 2 route, you may get some (very small) numerical errors. You can do it using `mod` to avoid this:

```
x = 16.625; 
dist = mod(x, 0.5); 
floorVal = x - dist; 
newVal = floorVal; 
if dist >= 0.25, newVal = newVal + 0.5; end
```

You could do it in fewer steps, but here I have broken it up so you can see what each step does.

Answer (score 1):

```
a=16.625;
b=floor(a);
if abs(a-b-0.5) <= 0.25
  a=b+.5;
else
  if a-b-0.5 < 0
    a=b;
  else
    a=b+1;
  end
end
```