# Round up or down decimal with different situation in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, decimal

I wrote application for **billing system** using C#.

**Total bill** can be rounded up or down to facilitate customers pay to cashier. It depends on the last value ending with cents. I use data type as **decimal** to make calculation.

When ending with cents **0.00, 0.01, 0.02** it will **round down** to **0.00**

Examples:

- 10.00, 10.01, or 10.02 round down to 10.00
- 10.10, 10.11, or 10.12 round down to 10.10

When ending with cents **0.03, 0.04, 0.05** it will **round up** to **0.05**

Examples :

- 10.03, 10.04, or 10.05 round up to 10.05
- 10.13, 10.14, or 10.15 round up to 10.15

When ending with cents **0.05, 0.06 or 0.07** it will **round down** to **0.05**

Examples :

- 10.05, 10.06, or 10.07 round down to 10.05
- 10.15, 10.16, or 10.17 round down to 10.15

When ending with cents **0.08 or 0.09 ** it will **round up** to **0.10**

Examples :

- 10.08 or 10.09 round down to 10.10
- 10.18 or 10.19 round down to 10.20

The problem now is I cannot use **Math.Round** because the answer is different and does not meet the system requirements. Let say my **total bill is 10.14**, it will **round down to 10.10** but the answer it should **round up to 10.15.**

I hope somebody help me to solved this problem.

Comment: Would multiplying by 2, rounding, and then dividing by 2 solve your issue?

Comment: @C.Evenhuis, thanks mate. Sorry I'm not good in mathematics

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was going to suggest an extension method which checks the last digit. But you can do this far simply by multiplying and ENSURING YOU'RE USING THE RIGHT ROUND TYPE.

You can get it from this answer pretty much.

[How do I round to the nearest 0.5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1329426/how-do-i-round-to-the-nearest-0-5)

Comment: Thanks for giving the link, simple and perfect!

Answer (score 3):

Simple answer is:

```
public decimal Round(decimal value)
{
    return Math.Round(value * 20) / 20;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Nicolas, I have try your code and is perfect.

Comment: If you use this, mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
static public decimal RoundToNickel(decimal value)
{
    var mod = value % 0.05M;

    if (mod >= 0.03M)
    {
        return value + 0.05M - mod;
    }

    return value - mod;
}
```