# Snap vector axis in script, like in the Unity editor?

Tags: c#

Unity has that feature where you can snap the axis  within the editor.

How can I do that in C# script? For example, say I want to be able to snap the X and Y floats to the nearest .5 world unit.

`-7.624` would become `-7.5`

`11.2324` would become `11`

`9.89786` would become `10`

`3.456` would become `3.5`

And so on.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I round to the nearest 0.5?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1329426/how-do-i-round-to-the-nearest-0-5)

Comment: Pease ***do not answer questions*** which are duplicates - this is an extremely basic general programming question which has been asked a million times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can round to the nearest x decimal places using `Math.Round()`, in order to get a round to the nearest .5 you could double the variable and then round to whole numbers.

```
var original = -7.624;
var rounded = Math.Round(original * 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero) / 2;
```

Edit: The point of [MidpointRounding](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.midpointrounding.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Comment: New users, please ***do not answer questions*** which are duplicates - this is an extremely basic general programming question which has been asked a million times.