# Round the fractional part to nearest multiple of .5 number

Tags: c#

What would be the code to round the fractional part of number to nearest multiple of .5 number ? For example I am looking for output something like this

Input => Output
40.11 => 40.10
40.12 => 40.10
40.13 => 40.15
40.14 => 40.15
40.16 => 40.15
40.17 => 40.15
40.18 => 40.20
40.19 => 40.20

My numbers have fractional part up to two decimal places.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: .. you mean nearest multiple of 0.5?

Comment: yes, that is correct

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So if you want to round to the nearest 'half', you need to double the number, round to one decimal place, then divide by two:

```
Math.Round(num * 2, 1) /2
```

So your example data:

```
Console.WriteLine(Math.Round(40.11 * 2, 1) / 2);
Console.WriteLine(Math.Round(40.12 * 2, 1) / 2);
Console.WriteLine(Math.Round(40.13 * 2, 1) / 2);
Console.WriteLine(Math.Round(40.14 * 2, 1) / 2);
Console.WriteLine(Math.Round(40.16 * 2, 1) / 2);
Console.WriteLine(Math.Round(40.17 * 2, 1) / 2);
Console.WriteLine(Math.Round(40.18 * 2, 1) / 2);
Console.WriteLine(Math.Round(40.19 * 2, 1) / 2);
```

Returns this (unformatted):

> 40.1
>   40.1
>   40.15
>   40.15
>   40.15
>   40.15
>   40.2
>   40.2

Comment: Awesome, thanks stuart. I was trying to find solution for a while.

Comment: Please consider moving (or adding) to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1329426/how-do-i-round-to-the-nearest-0-5 or edit the question so it no longer *looks* like duplicate and have some distinct search terms. Also it may be good idea to show use of `decimal` to properly keep 2 decimal digits...