# How do I fulfill these number rounding criteria?

Tags: c#, rounding

I've looked at a lot of threads but I can't find this specific answer.
I'm validating input in my controller, and the rules are:

1. Positive numbers only
2. Up to two decimal places
3. Round up to 0.05 (so 0.08 = 0.1 and 0.13 = 0.15)

I've been playing in .NET Fiddle and haven't got near an answer using various flavours of Floor, Ceiling, Round etc.

Thanks

EDIT: The suggested fix does not work for values > 0 && < 1

Comment: Example code with data types, please. Additional test data and expected results would also be helpful :: [mcve]

Comment: INPUT 
0.08 
EXPECTED
0.1

INPUT
0.13
EXPECTED OUTPUT
0.15

If it works for these, it will probably work in all my required scenarios.

Comment: Math.Round(x * 20) / 20

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I round to the nearest 0.5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1329426/how-do-i-round-to-the-nearest-0-5)

Answer (score 0):

Having reverted to my client, I can confirm that Arman's answer is correct for my requirements:

Math.Round(x * 20) / 20

Answer (score -1):

Multiply your rating by 2, then round using Math.Round(rating, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero), then divide that value by 2.

```
Math.Round(value * 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero) / 2
```

[Original Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1329426/how-do-i-round-to-the-nearest-0-5)

Comment: For values of 0.13 and 0.8 this returns 0, which is not what is required.