# How to round up and down double to the nearest interval in dart/flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to round down/up for example i want to round down 134.78 with nearest 0.5 the output should be 134.5 and if i round up the output should be 135.0 I tried `((134.78 / 0.5).floorToDouble() * 0.5)` but the result is 134.0 not 134.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Multiply your number by two before any calculations.
- Use the desired round feature. (Floor or Ceiling).
- Divide the result by two again:

```
  double a = 134.78;
  print((2*a).floorToDouble()/2); // prints 134.5
  print((2*a).ceilToDouble()/2);// prints 135
```

Which is the desired result.

You can read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1329426/10746978).