# How to I round decimals down to closest 0.5 with C#?

Tags: c#, rounding

I didn't find any good explanations about this when I google:d. All I found was how to round it to closest 0.5 both increasing and decreasing. (No I don't want to round both up and down, only down which is not the solution that was sent to me.)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I round to the nearest 0.5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1329426/how-do-i-round-to-the-nearest-0-5)

Comment: This issue is already solved [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1329426/how-do-i-round-to-the-nearest-0-5) :)

Comment: `y= Math.Round(x*2)/2`

Comment: These solutions are for rounding to closest 0.5, I want to round down to closest 0.5. Lets say I have 3.49, then I still want to round down to 3.0 and not to 3.50.

Answer (score 0):

How you might have answered the question yourself...

1. Documentation: [MS Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.round?view=net-6.0#System_Math_Round_System_Decimal_System_Int32_System_MidpointRounding_)
2. Experiment

(Note the `MidpointRounding` parameter)

```
Console.WriteLine("INTERVALS OF 0.5 (...-1.5, -1, -0.5, 0, 0.5, 1, 1.5...)");
Console.WriteLine("=======================================================");
Console.WriteLine("   N    def   0->   ->0 ->INF -INF<-  ->2");
Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------------");
for (var i = -2.1m; i < 2.2m; i += 0.2m)
{
  Console.WriteLine($"{i,4}: " +
    $"{(Math.Round(i * 2) / 2),5} " +
    $"{(Math.Round(i * 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero) / 2),5} " +
    $"{(Math.Round(i * 2, MidpointRounding.ToZero) / 2),5} " +
    $"{(Math.Round(i * 2, MidpointRounding.ToPositiveInfinity) / 2),5} " +
    $"{(Math.Round(i * 2, MidpointRounding.ToNegativeInfinity) / 2),5} " +
    $"{(Math.Round(i * 2, MidpointRounding.ToEven) / 2),5} ");
}
Console.WriteLine();

Console.WriteLine("INTERVALS OF 1 (...-1.5, -0.5, 0.5, 1.5...)");
Console.WriteLine("===========================================");
Console.WriteLine("   N    def   0->   ->0 ->INF -INF<-  ->2");
Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------------");
for (var i = -2.1m; i < 2.2m; i += 0.2m)
{
  Console.WriteLine($"{i,4}: {(Math.Round(i + 0.5m) - 0.5m),5} ");
}
```

Giving

```
INTERVALS OF 0.5 (...-1.5, -1, -0.5, 0, 0.5, 1, 1.5...)
=======================================================
   N    def   0->   ->0 ->INF -INF<-  ->2
-----------------------------------------
-2.1:    -2    -2    -2    -2  -2.5    -2
-1.9:    -2    -2  -1.5  -1.5    -2    -2
-1.7:  -1.5  -1.5  -1.5  -1.5    -2  -1.5
-1.5:  -1.5  -1.5  -1.5  -1.5  -1.5  -1.5
-1.3:  -1.5  -1.5    -1    -1  -1.5  -1.5
-1.1:    -1    -1    -1    -1  -1.5    -1
-0.9:    -1    -1  -0.5  -0.5    -1    -1
-0.7:  -0.5  -0.5  -0.5  -0.5    -1  -0.5
-0.5:  -0.5  -0.5  -0.5  -0.5  -0.5  -0.5
-0.3:  -0.5  -0.5     0     0  -0.5  -0.5
-0.1:     0     0     0     0  -0.5     0
 0.1:     0     0     0   0.5     0     0
 0.3:   0.5   0.5     0   0.5     0   0.5
 0.5:   0.5   0.5   0.5   0.5   0.5   0.5
 0.7:   0.5   0.5   0.5     1   0.5   0.5
 0.9:     1     1   0.5     1   0.5     1
 1.1:     1     1     1   1.5     1     1
 1.3:   1.5   1.5     1   1.5     1   1.5
 1.5:   1.5   1.5   1.5   1.5   1.5   1.5
 1.7:   1.5   1.5   1.5     2   1.5   1.5
 1.9:     2     2   1.5     2   1.5     2
 2.1:     2     2     2   2.5     2     2

INTERVALS OF 1 (...-1.5, -0.5, 0.5, 1.5...)
===========================================
   N    def   0->   ->0 ->INF -INF<-  ->2
-----------------------------------------
-2.1:  -2.5
-1.9:  -1.5
-1.7:  -1.5
-1.5:  -1.5
-1.3:  -1.5
-1.1:  -1.5
-0.9:  -0.5
-0.7:  -0.5
-0.5:  -0.5
-0.3:  -0.5
-0.1:  -0.5
 0.1:   0.5
 0.3:   0.5
 0.5:   0.5
 0.7:   0.5
 0.9:   0.5
 1.1:   1.5
 1.3:   1.5
 1.5:   1.5
 1.7:   1.5
 1.9:   1.5
 2.1:   2.5
```