# How do I round to the nearest 0.5

Tags: .net

I need increments as follows:

| input | rounded |
| --- | --- |
| 10.00 | 10.50 |
| 10.10 | 10.50 |
| 10.20 | 10.50 |
| 10.30 | 10.50 |
| 10.40 | 10.50 |
| 10.50 | 10.50 |
| 10.60 | 11.00 |
| 10.70 | 11.00 |
| 10.80 | 11.00 |
| 10.90 | 11.00 |

How to calculate the result in the easiest way

Comment: Why does `10` round to `10.5`, but `10.5` doesn't round to `11`? What're the correct values there?

Comment: Logic aside, there are a *lot* of similar questions already. First you'll have to explain the actual logic though. You seem to be rounding up to half, not rounding to the nearest half

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I round to the nearest 0.5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1329426/how-do-i-round-to-the-nearest-0-5)

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - That does not match what the OP is doing.

Comment: i hope 0-0.5 =0.5  0.6-0.9=1

Comment: @junchen - You'll need to be ***clearer***. I don't know what `0-0.5 =0.5 0.6-0.9=1` means. What is the ***rule*** you need.

Comment: So whole numbers round up to the next 0.5, but 0.5 numbers stay 0.5 - I must say this is a _very_ odd rounding scheme

Comment: @Jamiec - It is odd indeed. I'm waiting on clarification from the OP.

Comment: @Enigmativity except they have accepted your answer which is clearly right but doesnt do this strange specific rounding

Comment: @Jamiec - Yes, it gets weirder by the minute.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's your data:

```
var data = new[]
{
    new { input = 10.00, expected = 10.50 },
    new { input = 10.10, expected = 10.50 },
    new { input = 10.20, expected = 10.50 },
    new { input = 10.30, expected = 10.50 },
    new { input = 10.40, expected = 10.50 },
    new { input = 10.50, expected = 10.50 },
    new { input = 10.60, expected = 11.00 },
    new { input = 10.70, expected = 11.00 },
    new { input = 10.80, expected = 11.00 },
    new { input = 10.90, expected = 11.00 },
};
```

The normal way to round up to the nearest `0.5` is to use `Math.Ceiling(input * 2.0) / 2.0)`.

I would do that this way:

```
var output =
    data
        .Select(x => new
        {
            x.input,
            x.expected,
            actual = Math.Ceiling(x.input * 2.0) / 2.0
        });
```

That gives me:

[image: output]

I do note that `10` stays as `10` instead of `10.5` as per your requirement. I wonder if you got that requirement wrong since `10.5` doesn't round up?

Comment: One of the cases where looking for a duplicate takes 100x times longer than just answering.

Comment: i hope input 10.00 = result 10.50 ,i hope 0-0.5 =0.5 0.6-0.9=1

Comment: @junchen - You'll need to be specific as to what the rule is.

Comment: i hope 0-0.5 =0.5 0.6-0.9=1

Comment: @junchen - You'll need to be clearer. I don't know what `0-0.5 =0.5 0.6-0.9=1` means. What is the rule you need?